# Add Facebook SDK to my xCode project with Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I am following [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for iOS v3.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) to add Facebook SDK to my xCode project with `Storyboard`.

I did all the steps that described there.

We have a HelloFacebookSample in the Sample folder of Facebook SDK. it includes this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create Login View so that the app will be granted "status_update" permission.
    FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
    loginview.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];

    [loginview sizeToFit];
}

// Post Status Update button handler; will attempt to invoke the native
// share dialog and, if that's unavailable, will post directly
- (IBAction)postStatusUpdateClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    // Post a status update to the user's feed via the Graph API, and display an alert view
    // with the results or an error.
    NSString *name = self.loggedInUser.first_name;
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Updating status for %@ at %@",
                         name != nil ? name : @"me" , [NSDate date]];

    // if it is available to us, we will post using the native dialog
    BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                                                    initialText:nil
                                                                          image:nil
                                                                            url:nil
                                                                        handler:nil];
    if (!displayedNativeDialog) {

        [self performPublishAction:^{
            // otherwise fall back on a request for permissions and a direct post
            [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:message
                                        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                            [self showAlert:message result:result error:error];
                                            self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = YES;
                                        }];

            self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = NO;
        }];
    }
}
```

Then sample works fine, but when I want to have it on my own project, I have this problem:

It is successfully added the FBLoginView to my self.view. but when I `Login` and then want to post something I just go to this page:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any iOS6 Facebook account configured in the settings app? Normally you will get this message on iOS 6 when there are not accounts configured.

Comment: I want to test it on simulator. not the device. how can I do that? And as I said the sample worked for me, so why that works and my own not?

Comment: even in simulator go setting and add account in facebook so u can post

Comment: Did not work. The problem should be somewhere else. it should be in adding Facebook SDK to my own project with storyboard.

Comment: did u add framework #import<social/social.h>

Comment: If you have iOS 6 you should not add any frameworks. Use built in! (Social)

Comment: In the Hellosample also `social` did not imported, but any way I tried with import and without. non of them worked.

Comment: I think you should re-read facebook tutorial carefully. The describe everything you need.

Comment: ya in ios 6 add social framework its enough for facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. I needed to add these codes to my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // FBSample logic
    // if the app is going away, we close the session object
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // FBSample logic
    // We need to properly handle activation of the application with regards to SSO
    //  (e.g., returning from iOS 6.0 authorization dialog or from fast app switching).
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

They were not described in the link. It could be better to let the new users know about these details.